# What files have to shipped with the actual program?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, release

I know these are the include files(in c++) We have to compile them and then have to ship them with the actual binary. But I have a bit strange problem.I used windows.h in a program and I want to ship it but windows.h have other include files and so on.So I would have to ship whole windows sdk in the form of dll's .Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: You can't just require that your users have the Windows SDK installed? If they are doing C++ development on Windows, they probably will... If you are shipping to end users (not developers who would develop against your DLL) then you don't need to ship headers at all.

Comment: I can't tell if you are trying to ship a program, in which case include files, etc. are not needed or a library for other developers to use. Please be more detailed about exactly what you are trying to do, and what you have already tried.

Comment: You are not allowed to redistribute the Windows SDK anyway.

Comment: @cdhowie I tried shipping without dlls and it gave me an error

Comment: @S.Saad You need the DLLs. You *do not* need any headers (.h or .hpp files).

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235299.aspx).

Comment: @S.Saad You *can* ship your program without DLLs if you *statically* link to the VC runtime. If you are using Visual Studio, right-click on your project in the project explorer > Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Change the 'runtime library' setting to 'multithreaded' instead of 'multithreaded dll'. If you are using other libraries too, you have to link to the static version of these too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do *not* need to ship header files with a binary application.

You *do* however need to ship any shared libraries (DLL's on Windows) that your program depends on - and this includes the compilers runtime (the standard library etc) - static libraries are made part of the executable and thus do *not* need to be shipped separately.
If you are using Visual Studio then you need to ship the Visual Studio redistributables along with your program (google the version for your Visual Studio version) - for other compilers there are similar requirements.

Comment: Misses information about static linking.

Comment: @zett42 Right you are. Updated my answer.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  Thanks